# How to set custom font with specific size to Web View in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am trying to set Open sans with size 15 to a UIwebview. But i am not able to implement that successfully.

This is what i have been trying so far

```
let content = "<span><font size=12>" + jsonObject.stringValue + "</font></span>"
                self.webViewOutlet.loadHTMLString(content, baseURL: nil)
```

Can someone help to implement this

Thanks in advance

Comment: your `jsonObject.stringValue` value have the html content?

Comment: Please post `jsonObject.stringValue` content.

Comment: @Vahid  jsonObject.string value content value is formatted text. something like <strong> I am a <i>programmer</i></strong>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add `Open-Sans` or whatever font you like to your project:

[image: Add font to your project]

Set `span` font by CSS:

```
let content = "<span style=\"font-family: 'Open Sans';" + 
                             "font-size: 20px;\">" + 
                             jsonObject.stringValue + " </span>"
```